# JPA Criteria: Left outer joins instead of inner joins when doing projection from entity hierarchy

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

Given I have 1 parent entity and 2 children entities:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Notification {

    protected Long id;
    protected Long code;

    protected Notification() {
    }
}

@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "NOTIFICATION_ID")
public class Sms extends Notification {

    private String phoneNumber;
    private String smsText;

    public Sms() {
    }
}

@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "NOTIFICATION_ID")
public class Push extends Notification {

    private String application;
    private String pushText;
    
    public Push() {
    }
}
```

and I want to do projection using JPA criteria API as follows:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<NotificationSummary> query = builder.createQuery(NotificationSummary.class);
Root<Notification> root = query.from(Notification.class);

query.select(builder.construct(NotificationSummary.class,
        root.get("code"),
        builder.treat(root, Sms.class).get("smsText"),
        builder.treat(root, Push.class).get("pushText"),
        builder.treat(root, Sms.class).get("phoneNumber"),
        builder.treat(root, Push.class).get("application")
));

class NotificationSummary {

    private final Long code;
    private final String smsText;
    private final String pushText;
    private final String phoneNumber;
    private final String application;

    public NotificationSummary(Long code, String smsText, String pushText, String phoneNumber, String application) {
        this.code = code;
        this.smsText = smsText;
        this.pushText = pushText;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.application = application;     
    }
}
```

When I execute it it generates SQL query:

```
select
    notificati0_.code as col_1_0_,
    notificati0_3_.sms_text as col_5_0_,
    notificati0_2_.push_text as col_6_0_,
    notificati0_3_.phone_number as col_7_0_,
    notificati0_2_.application as col_8_0_ 
from
    notification notificati0_ 
inner join
    push notificati0_2_ 
        on notificati0_.id=notificati0_2_.notification_id 
inner join
    sms notificati0_3_ 
        on notificati0_.id=notificati0_3_.notification_id
```

I'd expect it would be left outer joins.

Can I somehow change it to be left outer joins instead of inner joins?

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately not possible because `TREAT` in HQL currently causes inner joins as the JPA specification wasn't very clear on the semantics. IMO it could be interpreted differently, but it is what it is right now.

In HQL you could actually omit `TREAT` to access subtype propeties implicitly which results in left joins, just like you'd expect it. If you don't want to rewrite your query in HQL, you might be able to use a different JPA Criteria implementation that essentially renders to JPQL/HQL. Blaze-Persistence, a library that works on top of JPA/Hibernate, supports many advanced SQL features while staying in the realm of the JPA model. Here is a link to the quick start for using the JPA Criteria implementation: https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#jpa-criteria-api-quick-start

You also need some [dependencies](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/core/manual/en_US/#getting-started-setup) but since you want to create a projection, you might also like [Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) which allows you to create projections in a more declarative fashion. Your use case could look like this with Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Notification.class)
public interface NotificationSummary {
    Long getCode();
    @Mapping("TREAT(this AS Sms).smsText")
    String getSmsText();
    @Mapping("TREAT(this AS Push).pushText")
    String getPushText();
    @Mapping("TREAT(this AS Sms).phoneNumber")
    String getPhoneNumber();
    @Mapping("TREAT(this AS Push).application")
    String getApplication();
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, lesson learnt about HQL being able to work without treat. HQL query now works for me.

Comment: I will try blaze-persistence project later on.